# mysql alert that it has been updated in PHP

Tags: java, php, mysql

I want the user to be informed that database is updated. I'm using PHP and mysql. There is a process behind which updates information in database. Once the process (java application) updates the database, how can I tell user the that they can view the processed information?

I don't have any idea at this moment how to do it or even is this possible?

Comment: you are doing updation with mysql queries?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check some script periodically (assuming your endclient is an webapp - probably using javascript) and raise an alert once the script returns the DB has been updated. Have a look on jQuery [polling](http://buntin.org/2008/09/23/jquery-polling-plugin/).

Comment: but currently im using xampp.xampp cant support jscript isnt it?

Comment: Never heard about this. Would be worth editing your question and add infromation about the end client, especialy about the technology you are using. There will be need for some kind of polling anyway.

Comment: im sorry, we dont need server to run javascript...my bad

Answer (score 0):

you could trigger ajax requests to poll information from the server, or you can try to use websockets to let the server

Comment: mr esskar, can u please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I've not fully understood your question.

If I've understood, you have a job that updates tables in the db.

While the job is running the user is not aware that the data are being updated and when the job has ended the user is not informed about.

I don't know if you can handle the tables, what kind of data are there, and if you can manage/control the java app...

If data and tables (and java app) are under my control, I will do the following:

- create a table called job_in_progress, with some fields like running as boolean, started_at as timestamp.
- modify the java app to update that table writing true in the running field when started, and writing false when ended.
- when the user goes to your PHP page, you check the job_in_progress table, and if the running field is true, it means that the java app is still running.

Another way: send an e-mail to the user when the java has ended (if the update process is heavy).

Comment: i noticed that there is a way to connect php and command prompt...but i keep looking on internet,never find.do you know?

Comment: PHP is an interpreter. You can write a script in PHP, then execute it like any other script, just providing info to the shell about the required PHP executable (i.e. in Windows you need php.exe to be in the path, and then run "php myscript.php" inside the command prompt). In *nix systems the script must begin with "#!/usr/bin/php".